# Path does not exist when saving attachment to OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, rename, attachment

I'm trying to download an Excel attachment from Outlook mail to my computer and rename it as the subject.

The computer is connected to one drive so my location file looks like this C:\Users\bob\OneDrive\Documents\Attachments

I get an error.
[image]

```vb
Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  'instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Sub DownStock(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
Dim Selection As Selection
Dim strSubject As String, strExt As String
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim strFile As String

Dim enviro As String
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
saveFolder = enviro & "\Documents\Attachments"

Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection

For Each itm In Selection
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        ' get the last 5 characters for the file extension
        strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 5)
        
        ' clean the subject
        strSubject = itm.Subject
        ReplaceCharsForFileName strSubject, "-"

        ' put the name and extension together
        file = saveFolder & strSubject & strExt

        objAtt.SaveAsFile file
    Next
Next
 
Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: SaveFolder needs a \ at the end.   `saveFolder = enviro & "\Documents\Attachments\"`

Comment: What is the exact file path generated in the code? Does the target folder exist on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that a specified folder doesn't exist on the disk. Make sure the file path is correct at runtime, for you need to run the code under the debugger and check the created file path string. Most probably you don't have the file path generated correctly.

When you run the following code:

```
' put the name and extension together
file = saveFolder & strSubject & strExt
```

The target folder's name is concatenated with a subject string.